# Multiple jQuery kwicks not working with different number of li

Tags: jquery, kwicks

http://jsfiddle.net/YkqKj/1/

This is a demo of multiple kwicks and it works fine.

Note: All the codes are from http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

However when I have different number of li, then it breaks and when I hover it expands as not expected:

```
/*
    Kwicks for jQuery (version 1.5.1)
    Copyright (c) 2008 Jeremy Martin
    http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

    Licensed under the MIT license:
        http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

    Any and all use of this script must be accompanied by this copyright/license notice in its present form.
*/

(function($){
    $.fn.kwicks = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            isVertical: false,
            sticky: false,
            defaultKwick: 0,
            event: 'mouseover',
            spacing: 0,
            duration: 500
        };
        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var WoH = (o.isVertical ? 'height' : 'width'); // WoH = Width or Height
        var LoT = (o.isVertical ? 'top' : 'left'); // LoT = Left or Top

        return this.each(function() {
            container = $(this);
            var kwicks = container.children('li');
            var normWoH = kwicks.eq(0).css(WoH).replace(/px/,''); // normWoH = Normal Width or Height
            if(!o.max) {
                o.max = (normWoH * kwicks.size()) - (o.min * (kwicks.size() - 1));
            } else {
                o.min = ((normWoH * kwicks.size()) - o.max) / (kwicks.size() - 1);
            }
            // set width of container ul
            if(o.isVertical) {
                container.css({
                    width : kwicks.eq(0).css('width'),
                    height : (normWoH * kwicks.size()) + (o.spacing * (kwicks.size() - 1)) + 'px'
                });                
            } else {
                container.css({
                    width : (normWoH * kwicks.size()) + (o.spacing * (kwicks.size() - 1)) + 'px',
                    height : kwicks.eq(0).css('height')
                });                
            }

            // pre calculate left or top values for all kwicks but the first and last
            // i = index of currently hovered kwick, j = index of kwick we're calculating
            var preCalcLoTs = []; // preCalcLoTs = pre-calculated Left or Top's
            for(i = 0; i < kwicks.size(); i++) {
                preCalcLoTs[i] = [];
                // don't need to calculate values for first or last kwick
                for(j = 1; j < kwicks.size() - 1; j++) {
                    if(i == j) {
                        preCalcLoTs[i][j] = o.isVertical ? j * o.min + (j * o.spacing) : j * o.min + (j * o.spacing);
                    } else {
                        preCalcLoTs[i][j] = (j <= i ? (j * o.min) : (j-1) * o.min + o.max) + (j * o.spacing);
                    }
                }
            }

            // loop through all kwick elements
            kwicks.each(function(i) {
                var kwick = $(this);
                // set initial width or height and left or top values
                // set first kwick
                if(i === 0) {
                    kwick.css(LoT, '0px');
                } 
                // set last kwick
                else if(i == kwicks.size() - 1) {
                    kwick.css(o.isVertical ? 'bottom' : 'right', '0px');
                }
                // set all other kwicks
                else {
                    if(o.sticky) {
                        kwick.css(LoT, preCalcLoTs[o.defaultKwick][i]);
                    } else {
                        kwick.css(LoT, (i * normWoH) + (i * o.spacing));
                    }
                }
                // correct size in sticky mode
                if(o.sticky) {
                    if(o.defaultKwick == i) {
                        kwick.css(WoH, o.max + 'px');
                        kwick.addClass('active');
                    } else {
                        kwick.css(WoH, o.min + 'px');
                    }
                }
                kwick.css({
                    margin: 0,
                    position: 'absolute'
                });

                kwick.bind(o.event, function() {
                    // calculate previous width or heights and left or top values
                    var prevWoHs = []; // prevWoHs = previous Widths or Heights
                    var prevLoTs = []; // prevLoTs = previous Left or Tops
                    kwicks.stop().removeClass('active');
                    for(j = 0; j < kwicks.size(); j++) {
                        prevWoHs[j] = kwicks.eq(j).css(WoH).replace(/px/, '');
                        prevLoTs[j] = kwicks.eq(j).css(LoT).replace(/px/, '');
                    }
                    var aniObj = {};
                    aniObj[WoH] = o.max;
                    var maxDif = o.max - prevWoHs[i];
                    var prevWoHsMaxDifRatio = prevWoHs[i]/maxDif;
                    kwick.addClass('active').animate(aniObj, {
                        step: function(now) {
                            // calculate animation completeness as percentage
                            var percentage = maxDif != 0 ? now/maxDif - prevWoHsMaxDifRatio : 1;
                            // adjsut other elements based on percentage
                            kwicks.each(function(j) {
                                if(j != i) {
                                    kwicks.eq(j).css(WoH, prevWoHs[j] - ((prevWoHs[j] - o.min) * percentage) + 'px');
                                }
                                if(j > 0 && j < kwicks.size() - 1) { // if not the first or last kwick
                                    kwicks.eq(j).css(LoT, prevLoTs[j] - ((prevLoTs[j] - preCalcLoTs[i][j]) * percentage) + 'px');
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        duration: o.duration,
                        easing: o.easing
                    });
                });
            });
            if(!o.sticky) {
                container.bind("mouseleave", function() {
                    var prevWoHs = [];
                    var prevLoTs = [];
                    kwicks.removeClass('active').stop();
                    for(i = 0; i < kwicks.size(); i++) {
                        prevWoHs[i] = kwicks.eq(i).css(WoH).replace(/px/, '');
                        prevLoTs[i] = kwicks.eq(i).css(LoT).replace(/px/, '');
                    }
                    var aniObj = {};
                    aniObj[WoH] = normWoH;
                    var normDif = normWoH - prevWoHs[0];
                    kwicks.eq(0).animate(aniObj, {
                        step: function(now) {
                            var percentage = normDif != 0 ? (now - prevWoHs[0])/normDif : 1;
                            for(i = 1; i < kwicks.size(); i++) {
                                kwicks.eq(i).css(WoH, prevWoHs[i] - ((prevWoHs[i] - normWoH) * percentage) + 'px');
                                if(i < kwicks.size() - 1) {
                                    kwicks.eq(i).css(LoT, prevLoTs[i] - ((prevLoTs[i] - ((i * normWoH) + (i * o.spacing))) * percentage) + 'px');
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        duration: o.duration,
                        easing: o.easing
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$().ready(function() {
                $('.kwicks').kwicks({
                    max : 390,
                    spacing : 5
                });
            });
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/RU4TB/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/RU4TB/1)

Comment: Without a [mcve], I suspect this question is (and was) too broad for Stack Overflow. I suggest that it is put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i have each kwick in its own tab, so I activated each kwick seperately - when tab was clicked. I know its not the best solution, but I cant find a better one.